# Full Table Scan while using if condition in query

Tags: mysql, database

i m having a situation that to use if condition in my `where` clause of the query. All the Fields having its own `indexes` which are used in if. But the query making the full `table` scan.
Can Any one help me to avoid full table scan?

My query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS fetchInfo 
WHERE IF(fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE='OP' 
AND fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0,fetchInfo.DUE_AMOUNT != 0,TRUE)
```

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
 BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS fetchInfo
WHERE
        IF(fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE='OP' AND fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0,fetchInfo.DUE_AMOUNT != 0,TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS fetchInfo 
WHERE IF(fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE='OP' 
AND fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0,fetchInfo.DUE_AMOUNT != 0,TRUE)
```

Your IF makes no sence. What it does is:

- If BILL_TYPE='OP',
- and BILL_CATEGORY=0,
- then the where-clause will be true when DUE_AMOUNT != 0
- else the where clause is always true.

But anyway, you don't need it. You can rewrite the query like this, using [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS fetchInfo 
WHERE (fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE='OP' 
  AND fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0 
  AND fetchInfo.DUE_AMOUNT != 0)
  OR fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE<>'OP'
  OR fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0
```

You should have one index on (BILL_TYPE,BILL_CATEGORY,DUE_AMOUNT), but even then, with the OR-clauses, it might still decide not to use the index. If that is the case, try rewriting as a union:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS fetchInfo 
    WHERE (fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE='OP' 
      AND fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0 
      AND fetchInfo.DUE_AMOUNT != 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS fetchInfo 
      WHERE fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE<>'OP'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS fetchInfo 
      WHERE fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0
```

You can do a SUM to add those.

Since you are actually accepting all values of the columns, maybe you don't even need a where clause...

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(
  IF(fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE='OP' 
    AND fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0 
    AND fetchInfo.DUE_AMOUNT != 0,
  1,
  0)) 
FROM BILL_PATIENT_BILL AS fetchInfo
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. Here i ve to check the DUE_AMOUNT != 0
 while fetchInfo.BILL_TYPE='OP' AND fetchInfo.BILL_CATEGORY=0 other wise no need but ur query returns only the rows with all the three matches.

Comment: Wait. If BILL_CATEGORY != 0, do you want the row to count or not? Because your current IF will return TRUE in that case (making the row count).

Comment: BILL_CATEGORY != 0 means it returns true so i want to count. I got my result but want to minimize scan.

Comment: Then either try de morgan or the UNION - they should use the indexes. You agree my WHERE clause is equivalent to yours, or have I made a mistake?